# Do I still need to use CORS?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, cors

I am developing a backend of web app, I have set up the global headers already for any route which are as following

Router.js file

```
Router.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, Accept, Accept-Version,Set-Cookie, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});
```

Server.js

```
//user defined middlewares
app.use("/",Router);
```

Do I need to set up cors again, because I am already allowing access from any source?, also I have allowed pre-flight requests

Answer (score 1):

These headers will be sent only when the root of your service `/` is requested. For any other endpoint such as `/getsomething` will not be set the CORS headers for.

If the use case of your server is only the root access - or you need the CORS headers to be set only for the root access, then NO - you don't have to do anything.

However, if you have more routes and you need them also to be CORS compatible, then you will have to use a general middleware above all routes.

One other point is that your CORS middleware should not send anything else for the `OPTIONS` preflight request. So, it is a good idea to end the response right there for the `OPTIONS` requests.

Here is the combined code:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, Accept, Accept-Version,Set-Cookie, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') 
    res.status(200).send();
  else
    next();     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think a module does not meet your requirements so you would have three choices:

1. Use another module that added your extra requirements(DRY).
2. Try to hack the module by some extra code of yours(< Dry).
3. Try to find that you can change the main module by making a pull request
   or just forking new one in order to expose your requirements(DRY).